# how to identify what device made a http post request?

Tags: google-chrome, http, post, web, mobile

I have a webpage to let people fill in a form and submit it. This submit is a HTTP POST request to my backend. For the sake of security, I want to keep a whitelist of devices that I consider their submitted information "safe". So I realize I will need to find a way to get some kind of "unique device ID" to identify what device made this POST.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A browser or other client presents itself in the HTTP request with the header User-Agent, and it can be forged easily. Relying on it for whitelisting would be a gap in security. (Cookies can be forged, too.)

However, if you trust some IP addresses, you can whitelist them.